# Почему отправляется дополнительный GET-запрос?

Tags: веб-программирование, http

Почему браузеры Yandex, Chrome, Mozilla отправляют дополнительный Get-запрос? Например, при подключении к серверу (ввожу в адресной строке 192.168.1.2), код которого представлен ниже, на консоли появляется следующее:

> New connection! Method: GET
>
> New connection! Method: GET

```
    package main

    import (
        "fmt"
        "net/http"
        //"database/sql"
        //_ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    )

    func requestHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Print("New connection! Method: " + r.Method + "\n")
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hi" /*pageBegin+index+pageEnd*/)
    }

    func main() {
        http.HandleFunc("/", requestHandler)
        http.ListenAndServe("192.168.1.2:80", nil)
    }
```

Также, при отправке других запросов (например POST), следом отправляется GET.

Comment: а какой ресурс запрашивается?

Comment: @Stranger in the Q
Просто обращаюсь к своему серваку.

Comment: @Stranger in the Q
неверно понял вопрос

Comment: распеечатайте кроме `r.Method` что запрашивает клиент

Comment: @Stranger in the Q /favicon.ico

Comment: я так и думал, это и есть ответ на Ваш вопрос

Comment: первый запрос - сама страница, второй - favicon

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Спасибо, прогуглил, стало ясно.